# Maven/Ant: Move a directory out of another directory of unknown name

Tags: maven, ant, directory

In a Maven project,
I have a zip containing a directory, which I need the content from.
I.e.

```
foo.zip
    somedir
         content
```

I don't know the name of `somedir`. But there's just this one dir.

How can I get `content` into some specific dir? (`target`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Ant 1.8.2 or newer, a `<cutdirsmapper>` strips a configured number of leading directories from each source file name:

```
<project name="ant-unzip-mapped-dir" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <unzip src="foo.zip" dest="target">
            <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
</project>
```

`somedir/content` becomes `content` in your example.

Source: [Ant's documentation on cutdirs-mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper)